# Creating form wizard with Qt

Tags: qt, pyqt, formwizard

Is it possible to create multi-steps form using Qt?

I want to divide the big one to few more simple steps one-by-one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the class [QWizard](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8/qwizard.html) and related.